# Is it possible to get the current URI from the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, url, model

I created a scaffold, but I'm trying to set some parameters according to the current URI (for example, if it's '/magazine/new', then do something, else if it's '/magazine/index', then do something else)

However, I can't manage to get the current URI by doing `logger.debug request.fullpath`to checkhow the current URI looks like, because I'm getting the error `undefined local variable or method 'request' for #<Class:0x0000000d329d78>`

How can I get what I need ? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 3.2 and 4+ you should be able to use:

```
logger.debug request.original_url
```

Here you have a full documentation of this method:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url